# How to detect if a button has been clicked OR an input's value has changed using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

My aim is to do something if an input's value changes OR a button is clicked.

I know how to implement these separately. For example:

```
$( 'form :input' ).change( function() {
    // Do something.
});

$( 'button' ).click( function() {
    // Do something.
});
```

But how can I implement them together? Here is some pseudo code example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
if ( button is clicked ) OR ( input value changed ) {
    // Do something.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about defining a function and just calling the same function in every case?

Something like this:

```
function f () {
    // do your stuff
}

$('form:input').change(f);
$('button').click(f);
```

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the same function as a handler.

```
function clickOrChangeHandler () {
    // do something
}

$('form:input').change(clickOrChangeHandler);

$('button').click(clickOrChangeHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Delegated events will allow combining both selectors and events:

```
$(document).on('change click', 'form :input, button', function() {
    // Do something.
    alert("event from " + this.outerHTML);
});
```

This will however trigger twice for a checkbox (change and click).

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/zqvs0ne9/1/

Comment: Many of my input fields happen to be checkboxes... is there a way around the double-trigger?

Comment: @henrywright: Unfortunately not without adding additional checks inside the handler. The one you marked as answer is the simplest way. This was just to make you aware of an alternative :)

Comment: Ah Ok. Thanks for the info, I'm sure I can use this in another project!